# Parse: query class property and sort on proximity

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a backend for an app that lists restaurants. I want to the user to query for a restaurant (e.g. Subway) and have the closest ones listed near the top of the search result. In other words sorted by proximity. I have Geopoints for all my locations.

My code thus far:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Restaurant');

query.fullText( 'name', 'Subway );

query.find()
then(function( results ) {               
    populateList( results );
} )
.catch( function( error ) {
    // There was an error.
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Restaurant');

query.fullText('name', 'Subway');
query.near('theNameOfTheFieldThatContainsTheRestaurantLocation', theUserLocation);

query.limit(10);

query.find()
  .then(function (results) {
    populateList(results);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // There was an error.
  });
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#parsegeopoint

Comment: I can't get that to work. It seems as though query.near is not supported in sub-queries???

Comment: What's the error message that you have? Geo queries are not supported in subqueries or compound queries as you can see [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#compound-queries).

Comment: I get error code `1` returned which is an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. Both the `near` and `fullText` queries work individually.

Comment: I got it. I think they will probably not work together. I think you can't create a query with full text search and geo query at same time. Do you mind to open an issue in the project GitHub repo for further investigation?